# How can I merge rectangles with small area (OpenCV, Python)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, merge, rectangles

I'm using OpenCV in order to detect rectangles in my image so I can crop them later: (rectangles contains products).
The first thing I have done was detecting Vertical and Horizontal lines, combine them to get this picture : [Image_With_Small_rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfgfv.png)

As you can see on the left side of my image, I have got some indesirable vertical/horizontal lines, that create small rectangles.
As I'm new to OpenCV, I want to know if it's possible to merge rectangle with a small area! (if area > min_area) merge_rectangle
So I can get an image clean like this one : [Clean_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Mah.png)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the code of what you tried? If you used Houghlines, you might want play around with `minLineLength` and `maxLineGap`

Comment: OCV's `cv::Rect` has the `area()` method which returns the area of the rectangle. As for the rest, you ll have to determine which rects are next to each other and how to merge them, yourself (not really hard)

Comment: I have an idea. Since the indesirable lines always has an end that has only one black pixel neighbor, we can detect these end points. Then we detect the point where a horizontal line and a vertical line meet, to have the position of the other end of the line. Then eliminate the pixels in between.

Comment: Nice idea! I'll be working on it.